# C++ Indenting output class inheriting ofstream

Tags: c++, c++11, std, ofstream, manipulators

So I want to write an indent output class that can be used like this:

```
Debug f;
f.open("test.txt");
f << Debug::IndS << "Start" << std::endl;
f << Debug::Ind << "test" << std::endl;
f << Debug::IndE << "End" << std::endl;
```

which would output:

```
Start
    test
End
```

So IndS would print out current indent and increment indent, Ind would print out the current indent and IndE would decrement indent and print out the current indent. I have tried to create it like so:

```
class Debug : public std::ofstream {
    public:
        Debug();
        ~Debug();

    private:
        std::string IndentText;
        int _Indent;

    public:
        void SetIndentText(const char* Text);
        inline void Indent(int Amount);
        inline void SetIndent(int Amount);

        inline std::ofstream& Ind (std::ofstream& ofs);
        inline std::ofstream& IndS(std::ofstream& ofs);
        inline std::ofstream& IndE(std::ofstream& ofs);
};

Debug::Debug () : std::ofstream() {
    IndentText = "    ";
}

Debug::~Debug () {
}

void Debug::SetIndentText (const char* Text) {
    IndentText = Text;
}

void Debug::Indent (int Amount) {
    _Indent += Amount;
}

void Debug::SetIndent(int Amount) {
    _Indent = Amount;
}

std::ofstream& Debug::Ind (std::ofstream& ofs) {
    for (int i = 0;i < _Indent;i++) {
        ofs << IndentText;
    }
    return ofs;
}

std::ofstream& Debug::IndS (std::ofstream& ofs) {
    ofs << Ind;
    _Indent++;
    return ofs;
}

std::ofstream& Debug::IndE (std::ofstream& ofs) {
    _Indent--;
    ofs << Ind;
    return ofs;
}
```

So I think there are a few problems with this:

1. **It does not compile.** Errors with `no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')   ofs << Ind; candidates are:` blah blah
2. **I don't override all constructors.** Is there a way to do this? I think I just have to rewrite all the constructors to do `IndentText = "    ";` and delegate the overloaded constructor

Could someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't inherit `std::ofstream`, provide an [I/O manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) instead.

Comment: I have tried to provide the manipulator's ``Ind`` ``IndS`` and ``IndE`` but this requires storing extra information which so I think creating a special version of an ofstream would work

Comment: Heve a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599807/how-to-add-indention-to-the-stream-operator) it's a cleaner solution, should work with any stream (`cout`, `stringstream`, `fstream`)

Comment: Here are some more hekpful links about how to write an I/O manipulator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535444/custom-manipulator-for-c-iostream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream

Comment: Also, for redirecting constructors, use something like `template<class... T> Child(T... && v) : Parent(std::forward<T>(v)...) {}`

Comment: Also you may extern the information about the actual indentation level into another class used by your I/O manipulators commonly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ haha, visited all your links already :L

Comment: @Antoine turns out my C++ is worse than I thought, not sure how to use your 2nd suggestion, your first suggestion looks interesting, though it seems to be based on reading characters while they are outputted and indents every newline, (which is probably what I want) but to use it in the way described, do you know what could be done? Manipulators might be useful

Comment: @Winestone Well, may be a simple I/O manipulator isn't the right way to go. Though inheriting `std::ofstream` certainly isn't either. What you could do is having kind of a `Logger` class, that manages a `std::ostream` internally and exposes the `<<operator` in the same way it's done for `std::ostream`. Then you can provide additional public methods, to manipulate the level indentations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sounds interesting, I'll try that, do you know anyway to expose all of ``std::ofstream``'s constructors?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how would I expose the ``operator<<``? Do I make a copy of the ``std::ofstream``'s ``operator<<``s and just redirect the arguements? or would I just public the ``std::ofstream``?

Comment: @Winestone You have free friend functions for `Logger` like this `template <typename T> Logger& operator<<(Logger& log, T op) { log.os << op; return log; }`

Comment: For the constructor thing, google `C++ perfect forwarding` and `variadic templates`, both new to C++11. But [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119929/forwarding-all-constructors-in-c0x) you could just simply do `using Parent::Parent` (where `Parent` is `std::ostream` or `std::ofstream` in your `Debug` child class, and the compiler will take care of the rest)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ do you think this would be ok? http://ideone.com/6Xcl2c

Comment: @Antoine do you think this would be ok? http://ideone.com/6Xcl2c

Comment: @Winestone For using something like a plain manipulator, yes. I'd prefer something in the way I've given in my answer though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would except for the slightly decreased flexibility :S

Comment: @Winestone You can still write I/O manipulator style manipulators for `Logger` as well, as long these appear as the first argument in the `operator<<()` chain. It's flexible as can be IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess you could, I'll mark yours as the answer and add my other solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually shouldn't inherit `std::ostream` or implementations of it like `std::ofstream`. Wrap them into another class instead.

Here's a short sketch of my ideas mentioned in the comments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Logger {
public:
    Logger(ostream& os) : os_(os), curIndentLevel_(0) {}
    void increaseLevel() { ++curIndentLevel_; }
    void decreaseLevel() { --curIndentLevel_; }

private:
    template<typename T> friend ostream& operator<<(Logger&, T);

    ostream& os_;
    int curIndentLevel_;
};

template<typename T> 
ostream& operator<<(Logger& log, T op) {
    for(int i = 0; i < log.curIndentLevel_ * 4; ++i) {
        log.os_ << ' ';
    }
    log.os_ << op;
    return log.os_;
}

int main() {
    Logger log(cout);
    log.increaseLevel();
    log << "Hello World!" << endl;
    log.decreaseLevel();
    log << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
    Hello World!
Hello World!
```

[**Live Sample**](http://ideone.com/qk5f4b)

---

Here's a little variant, showing how you can shortcut the coding with `operator<<()` overloads:

```
class Logger {
public:
    Logger(ostream& os) : os_(os), curIndentLevel_(0) {}
    Logger& increaseLevel() { ++curIndentLevel_; return *this; }
    Logger& decreaseLevel() { --curIndentLevel_; return *this; }

    // ... as before ...        
};

int main() {
    Logger log(cout);

    log.increaseLevel() << "Hello World!" << endl;
    log.decreaseLevel() << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Sample**](http://ideone.com/vcMDxL)

The same way you can go to provide additional I/O manipulator style free functions.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class IndentClass {
    public:
        IndentClass();
        ~IndentClass();

    private:
        std::string IndentText;
        int _Indent;

    public:
        inline void SetIndentText(const char* Text);
        inline void Indent(int Amount);
        inline void SetIndent(int Amount);

        inline void ind (std::ostream& ofs);

        class Ind_t {
            public:
                IndentClass& state;
                Ind_t (IndentClass& _state) : state(_state) {}
                friend inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, Ind_t& ind);
        };
        class IndS_t {
            public:
                IndentClass& state;
                IndS_t (IndentClass& _state) : state(_state) {}
                friend inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, IndS_t& ind);
        };
        class IndE_t {
            public:
                IndentClass& state;
                IndE_t (IndentClass& _state) : state(_state) {}
                friend inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, IndE_t& ind);
        };
        Ind_t Ind;
        IndS_t IndS;
        IndE_t IndE;
};

IndentClass::IndentClass () : IndentText("    "), _Indent(0), Ind(*this), IndS(*this), IndE(*this) {

}

IndentClass::~IndentClass () {
}

void IndentClass::SetIndentText (const char* Text) {
    IndentText = Text;
}

void IndentClass::Indent (int Amount) {
    _Indent += Amount;
}

void IndentClass::SetIndent(int Amount) {
    _Indent = Amount;
}

void IndentClass::ind (std::ostream& ofs) {
    for (int i = 0;i < _Indent;i++) {
        ofs << IndentText;
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, IndentClass::Ind_t& ind) {
    ind.state.ind(ofs);
    return ofs;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, IndentClass::IndS_t& inds) {
    inds.state.ind(ofs);
    inds.state.Indent(1);
    return ofs;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ofs, IndentClass::IndE_t& inde) {
    inde.state.Indent(-1);
    inde.state.ind(ofs);
    return ofs;
}

int main () {
    IndentClass i;

    std::cout << i.IndS << "test" << std::endl;
    std::cout << i.Ind << "test" << std::endl;
    std::cout << i.IndE << "test" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone Example](http://ideone.com/6Xcl2c)