# Template argument deduction failure for manipulators when forwarding to std::ostream <<

Tags: c++

I ran into some trouble trying to inherit `std::ostream` and using a custom `operator <<` which is basically doing some work and then forwarding to `std::ostream <<`, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
struct ostream : std::ostream{
    using std::ostream::ostream;
    template<typename T>
    ostream &operator <<(T &&arg){
        //some work...
        static_cast<std::ostream&>(*this) << std::forward<T>(arg);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    ostream cc(std::cout.rdbuf());
    cc << "hello world";
    //cc << "hello world" << std::endl; //couldn't deduce template parameter `T`
}
```

The problem is when using manipulators, like in the line I have commented out, gcc complains about [*template argument deduction/substitution failed:*].

Do I have to set the template type explicitly?, if so how?, because I cannot use the in class `std::ostream::operator <<` due to incompleteness.

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Lbcerqt6mi5A3FZ2)

---

Edit

I have just defined the custom `operator <<` as a free function so not inside the class `ostream`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
struct ostream : std::ostream{
    using std::ostream::ostream;
};
template<typename T>
ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, T &&arg)
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(os) << std::forward<T>(arg);
    return os;
}
int main(){
    ostream cc(std::cout.rdbuf());
    cc << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

and it is working as expected, also for manipulators. Not sure why this makes a difference here, maybe someone could clarify this for me

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633864/how-do-the-stream-manipulators-work

Comment: Assuming, your actual intention is to add some additional formatting to a standard output stream: I once did it (successully) based on this: [SO: How to add indention to the stream operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600752/7478597). (Btw. it doesn't require overloading of stream operators (`<<`).)

Comment: @Scheff Thank you for your comment. It is going to be a circular_file struct `circular_ofstream` for server logs, where I am setting locks in `operator <<`. Therefore I stick to it.

Comment: Ah, OK. I must admit that your solution looks even more straight forward then the one I linked (although (for additional formatting) it's probably easier to manipulate the resulting character "stream" after stream operators have been processed.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the manipulators are templated, and your class does not provide the information needed for selecting the right template parameters for `std::endl`. You should overload the `operator<<` for the manipulators:

```
struct ostream : std::ostream{
    using std::ostream::ostream;

    template<typename T>
    ostream &operator <<(T &&arg){
        //some work...
        static_cast<std::ostream&>(*this) << std::forward<T>(arg);
        return *this;
    }
    ostream &operator<<(
      std::ostream &(*manip)(std::ostream&)) {
              //some work...
        static_cast<std::ostream&>(*this) <<manip;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Note that the code in the question failed for the same reason that the following fails:

```
auto manip = std::endl;
```

It simply can't deduce the template parameters of `endl`.

**Update**

The alternative that makes the ovloading as a free function does not do what one may expect:

```
template<typename T>
ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, T &&arg)
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(os) << std::forward<T>(arg);
    return os;
}
int main(){
    ostream cc(std::cout.rdbuf());
    cc << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

The operator that gets `std::endl` is from the original iostream library. The compiler does not execute the overloaded function in this case, and that's why there is no compilation error.

If you don't want to overload the manipulators, you can provide the template parameters explicitly:

```
cc << "hello world" << std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>;
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. I actually wanted to avoid to overload for manipulators. Anyway I found out that overloading can be avoided if the `operator <<` is defined as a free function (see edit) . Why can it deduce the template parameter when defined as free function but not in class?

Comment: I dont really understand why for the free function itself (which is template too), I mean there is a `T` which has to be deduced too, there is no deduction failure then. I dont see the difference to defining it inside the class or outside for type deduction, but I am probably just wrong.

Comment: @czorp because the wrong free function is called, not yours. The wrong function overloads the manipulators

Comment: Ohhhhh ofc. omg I am so stupid XD. Thank you very much!!! Thank you for your time